# Replicate iOS Pattern: Instagram Search-Style Swiping Tabs

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, swipe

I'm starting a new **iOS** project in **Swift**, and my experience programming native iOS applications is minimal, so please bear with me if I use some whacky terminology or overlook some simple solutions.

I'm looking to replicate a pattern in the Instagram application, as seen here:

[Selected Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vkBd.jpg)

[Swiping Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2R0N.jpg)

For those who don't use Instagram, what's essentially going on here is **something like a UIPageViewController** (with swiping functionality), but with the tabs on top indicating the selected page.

Like in Instagram, I'm planning to have this functionality **within a child UIViewController of a UITabBarController** (you can see the "main" tabs on the bottom).

What I started out doing was creating static tabs and adding left and right gesture recognizers to the child UIViewController, which would change the page and update the indicator of the selected page on the tabs.

This *works* but I'm not really loving the way it looks, nor the way it's written. I don't like the idea of needing 2 instances of the tabs, and that certainly *doesn't* seem to be the way Instagram is doing it, because as shown in the second image, **the indicator slides between the tabs.**

I've searched a fair bit, but all references to replicating Instagram patterns seem to be outdated and don't address this specific element. Like I said, though, I haven't been programming native iOS for very long (I'm an Android developer and have used Xamarin for iOS), so it's possible I'm just not using the right keywords.

I'd appreciate any help y'all can offer!

Thanks

Comment: Something like  [this](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) or do you want to implement it from the scratch?

Comment: @pandarencodemaster Bingo! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it is what you've searched.I'm not sure if I should add it as an answer.

Comment: @pandarencodemaster I'm not sure what the StackOverflow etiquette is, but I'd say go for it; it definitely answered my question haha